# Play Framework Scala format large JSON (No unapply or unapplySeq function found)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I need to receive a big JSON on my server (more than 22 fields).
I have a case class with a lot of fields:

```
case class Filters(objectType: Option[String] = None,
     deal: Option[String] = None,
     roomsCount: Option[String] = None,
     region: Option[Int] = None,
     district: Option[Int] = None,
     direction: Option[Int] = None
     ...
)
```

And JSON format function in controller:

`implicit val filtersFormat = Json.format[Filters]`

At compilation I have error:

```
[error] WebSockets.scala:18: No unapply or unapplySeq function found
[error]   implicit val filtersFormat = Json.format[Filters]
[error]                                          ^
```

Is there a way to solve the problem without breaking JSON to small parts?

Comment: Break your `case class` out, and have the `apply` function create a nested `case class` structure.

Comment: is this not possible without breaking the case class. My json has more than 100 fields and I have already broken it into 5 case classes, further nesting it is complicating my business logic too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
case class Filters(part1: Part1, part2: Part2, ...)

case class Part1(
    field1: Field1,
    field2: Field2,
    ...
    field10: Field10,
)

object Part1 {
    implicit val part1Format = Json.format[Part1]
}

...

object Filters {
    implicit val filtersReads = (
        JsPath.read[Part1] and
        JsPath.read[Part2] and
        ...
    )(Filters.apply _)

    implicit val filtersWrites = (
        JsPath.write[Part1] and
        JsPath.write[Part2] and
        ...
    )(unlift(Filters.unapply))
}
```

Comment: Please do it without breaking into small parts, as per the question.

Answer (score 8):

As @Sawyer mentioned you can use an [external library](https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions). This was taken from [this blog](https://blog.datumbrain.com/2018/10/22/json-format-more-than-22-case-class.html).

First add the lib dependency to your SBT

```
libraryDependencies += "ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.42.0"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import ai.x.play.json.Jsonx
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class Foo(a1: String, a2: String, a3: String, a4: String, a5: String,
               a6: String, a7: String, a8: String, a9: String, a10: String,
               a11: String, a12: String, a13: String, a14: String, a15: String,
               a16: String, a17: String, a18: String, a19: String, a20: String,
               a21: String, a22: String, a23: String)

object Foo {
  implicit val f: OFormat[Foo] = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Foo]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same pb and find a solution by using

```
Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Filters]
```

The explication can be found
https://harrylaou.com/playframework/bigjson/