# Serializing Case Class

Tags: json, scala, serialization

This is kind of a strange issue I've been having. I had a case class with many parameters, including a string, and was able to serialize it to JSON straightforwardly using Play's Format. Then, I added another parameter - a String - and it starts complaining that

> No unapply or unapplySeq function found

The original looked like this:

```
case class PushMessage(stageOne: Boolean, stageTwo: Boolean, stageThree: Boolean, stageFour: Boolean, stageFive: Boolean,
                   highestStage: Int, iOSTotal: Int, androidTotal: Int, iOSRunningCount: Int, androidRunningCount: Int,
                   vendorId: String, androidProblem: Boolean, iOSComplete: Boolean, androidComplete: Boolean,
                   totalStageThrees: Int, totalStageFours: Int, totalStageFives: Int, expectedTotals: Int,
                   latestUpdate: Long, iOSProblem: Boolean, startTime: Long, date: Long)
```

The new one looks like

```
case class PushMessage(stageOne: Boolean, stageTwo: Boolean, stageThree: Boolean, stageFour: Boolean, stageFive: Boolean,
                   highestStage: Int, iOSTotal: Int, androidTotal: Int, iOSRunningCount: Int, androidRunningCount: Int,
                   vendorId: String, androidProblem: Boolean, iOSComplete: Boolean, androidComplete: Boolean,
                   totalStageThrees: Int, totalStageFours: Int, totalStageFives: Int, expectedTotals: Int,
                   latestUpdate: Long, iOSProblem: Boolean, startTime: Long, date: Long, topics: String)
```

The only difference is the parameter topics.

My serializer looks like:

```
    object PushMessage {

  implicit val pushMessageFormat = Json.format[PushMessage]

}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play uses macros and tuples to derive the Json instance.  The problem is that tuples are limited to 22 fields in Scala (at least at the moment).

That means that Play won't be able to automatically derive a Json instance, although you can work around it by manually writing it.

You can find more info here: [Play Framework Scala format large JSON (No unapply or unapplySeq function found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411165/play-framework-scala-format-large-json-no-unapply-or-unapplyseq-function-found)